# getting 404 error using flask-restless

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restless

I have an existing mysql database, and I'm trying to create an API to access it, but I'm receiving a 404 error. I have two versions of code that don't work.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

URL I'm using: http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/email

v1:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.restless import APIManager
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://pathtodb/emails'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Email(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'emails'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    status = db.Column(db.String(20))
    email = db.Column(db.String())

    def __init__(self, status, email):
        self.status = status
        self.email = email

api_manager = APIManager(app, flask_sqlalchemy_db=db)
api_manager.create_api(Email, methods=['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'PUT'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

v2:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.restless import APIManager
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

app = Flask(__name__)
Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://pathtodb/emails', echo=True)
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)

class Email(Base):
    __tablename__ = Table('emails', metadata, autoload=True)
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    status = Column(String(20))
    email = Column(String())


api_manager = APIManager(app, flask_sqlalchemy_db=engine)
api_manager.create_api(Email, methods=['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'PUT'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

URL I'm using: http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/email

Comment: what url are you using to access the api ?

Comment: @PRMoureu - http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/email

Comment: try with  http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/emails, the tablename is plural

Comment: @PRMoureu I though I needed to use the class name 'email', but I need to use the table name as you suggested. I'd like to mark this as the answer, but I can't since it's a comment. Thank you, and I'll mark it as solved if you'd like to answer it.

Comment: i thought it was a typo, but you're right it could be confusing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `flask-restless` the links are generated automatically when the method `api_manager.create_api()` is called, with this format :

```
'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/{tablename}'  # default domain and port
```

where `{tablename}` is the `__tablename__` given to the model class, not the class name called in the method.

The doc mentioned an example [here](https://github.com/jfinkels/flask-restless/blob/master/examples/quickstart.py#L38).

Comment: btw, not sure about the version you are using, but the import could be `from flask_restless import APIManager` to avoid a deprecated warning